# Django template with if - no clue what's wrong

Tags: django, if-statement, templates

I'm new to Django and followed the Django tutorial to understand and adapt to my needs.

I am trying the following template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}

  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
         <h1>List of my Projects</h1>
         {% if myproject_list %} 
         <ul>
            {% for projectuser in myproject_list %}
             -{{ user.username }}-<br>
             -{{ projectuser.User }}-<br><br>  
  
              {% if  projectuser.User  ==  user.username  %}
                 <li> x 
                    {{ projectuser.Project }}
                 </li>
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
          {% else %}
            <p>There are no projects to list.</p>
          {% endif %}
    {% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a></li>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

some code in there like

```
   -{{ user.username }}-<br>
   -{{ projectuser.User }}-<br><br>
```

are just for debugging.
with those two lines I get the usernames which I would like to apply here:

```
 {% if  projectuser.User  ==  user.username  %}
```

However the if is always not true!!
What am I missing!?!?!?!?

PS:
I tried to find a solution with some posts here.
Couldn't solve my problem

Comment: Can you also share the model associated with it?

Comment: Have you checked what the values are? In the html put `<!--DBG  "{{projectuser.User}}" "{{user.username}}" -->` and view page source, search for DBG. (Or you can omit HTML commenting if your html is simple). `User` with capital U loks like a mistake. That's normally the python class, not a field name.

Comment: projectuser.User what is exatly? it is linked with the User model?

Comment: please provide more details, your views and your models.